# add uploadify upload function to form submit button

Tags: uploadify, form-submit

I am using Uploadify uploader for my form submission which include some other text field. I set the auto upload to 'false' so that I could trigger the upload process of all the files user have chosen when the form submit button is clicked which would submit both the files and data in the text field to my DB.

But I couldn't figure that out. please help me on this.